# Object Data Source in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2012, objectdatasource

I'm trying to follow various tutorials on how to create LINQ to SQL classes and they all say I should connect to the Object Data Source. However there's no such source available to select in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web. Is this a limitation of the Express for Web edition? I have tried to find info on this, but haven't found anything. Is there a workaround?

[image: change data source dialogue in visual studio 2012 express for web]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. This should be done through Project->Add New Data Source. Not Tools->Connect to Database or Database Explorer.